# Is there any difference between the queries , because I am seeing a difference in the output

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is the first query

```
SELECT left.description, right.description 
FROM left JOIN right ON left.id = right.id;
```

and here is the second query

Query - 2

```
SELECT l.description AS left, r.description AS right
FROM left as l
JOIN right as r
ON l.id = r.id;
```

Comment: Queries are exactly the same. What's the expected output for you, and what do you get? Difference can be in ordering of data, because you didn't add ORDER BY at the end

Comment: thats the actual worry, I also think that they are the same but executing them in XAMPP give me different results for the same tables.

Comment: from the first query I am getting the entries of 2nd table whereever the condition is matching, but from the second query I am getting entries of both table whereever the condition is matching

Comment: Escape the left and right words in both queries and try running them again.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't expect either to actually run, because `left` and `right` are reserved words in MySQL.  However, I think I understand the question -- and these aren't your real names.

The only real distinction that I see is in the naming of the result set `description, description` versus `left, right`.  If you are trying to retrieve the columns using an application (such as PHP), then you will see only one `description` field.

The formatting of the query on different lines and the use of table aliases should have no affect whatsoever on the query plan that is generated.  Those are conventions for people reading the queries.